# Issue Extracting the div tag from inside another div

Tags: javascript, html

HI i am working in Javascript.
My code is:

```
var oldData  = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
alert(oldData);

alert is shown as : text<img src="add-icon.png"><div id = "1"></div>
```

Here old data contains a text an image tag and a div tag. The issue is I want to just access the div tag id but i dnt know how to get it. Please help.
Thanx in advance

Comment: If you're willing to use jQuery it's as simple as `$(elem).children("div").attr("id")`

Comment: Well what does this $(elem) mean ??

Comment: You mean i have to do this like below

Comment: var test =  $(elem).children("div").attr("id");
                     alert(test);

Comment: If you have an element's ID, then `elem` is `document.getElementById(id)`, equivalently `$("#"+id)`. In this case, you can also do `$("#"+id+" > div").attr("id")` (think: CSS selectors on steroids)

Comment: i don't want to search the whole document instead just search that oldData variable.

Comment: Don't worry, `$("#id > div")` is just as fast as `$("#id").children("div")`, or maybe even a little bit faster; browsers know what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing with using vanilla JavaScript is, you've got to write all the filters yourself :)

```
var oldData = document.getElementById(id), firstDiv, id;
firstDiv = filterElements(node);
id = firstDiv.id;

function filterElements( node ){
     var children = parent.childElements, firstDiv, node;
     for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i += 1 ){
         node = children[i];
         if (node.tagName && node.nodeType && node.nodeType === 1 && 
                 node.tagName.toLowerCase() === "div"){
              firstDiv = node;
              break;
         }
     }
      return firstDiv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the use of jQuery. Then you can access the id of the div within its element stored as `elem` as

```
$(elem).children("div").attr("id")
```

If you know the parent by ID, then you can do this:

```
$("#"+id).children("div").attr("id")
```

or even this:

```
$("#"+id+">div").attr("id")
```

Of course, if you want the ID just to access an element, then you don't need to. To append a new image to the div:

```
$("#"+id+">div").append("<img ...>")
```

or

```
$("#"+id+">div").append($("<img>"). ...)
```

Also, I recommend using classes instead of childhood to identify elements:

```
$("#"+id+" .image-holder").append(...)
```

or

```
$("#"+id+").find(".image-holder").append(...)
```

Comment: sigh, why oh why would you push the OP to use jQuery for just this?

Comment: The thing with using vanilla JavaScript is, you've got to write all the filters yourself :)